# Making an overridden abstract method in a subclass "private"

Tags: python, oop

Say I have a an abstract base class, and a subclass that is also abstract:

```
class Daemon(object)::
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def __init__(self, pid_file):
        ...

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def run(self):
        return


class Worker(Daemon):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def run(self):
        # do stuff
        self.process()

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def process(self):
        """
        Override this method when subclassing Worker.
        """
        return
```

When other developers build new actual "working" Worker sub-classes, I'd like to make it clear that they shouldn't mess with the run method. If I use `__run` it hints that the method is private, but then I'm creating a private abstract method in `Daemon`, which is a bit confusing. It also seems odd to have it protected using `_run` because I don't want Worker sub-classes to mess with it. I realize the private and protected names are just useful conventions in Python, I just want to make it clear for others how to build new Worker sub-classes.

Is there a Pythonic convention to follow in this case? Or is this just a matter of making the documentation clear?

Comment: Should your user subclass `Daemon` directly? If not, I see no problem in making the `run` method private(i.e. `_run`), if yes than `run` is a public method that they ought to be able to reimplement, or you are going against the least astonishment principle. In any case document the `Worker`'s `run` method well(e.g. "every subclass must call the base class `run` method" and similar warnings if they apply to the situation).

Comment: if `Worker.run` is not the same thing as `Daemon.run`; as in, `Worker.run` is not part of its public interface, then `Worker` violates [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle); an instance of `Worker` would not be acceptable to something that expects an instance of `Daemon`, since the former does not have a (public) `run()` method.  should `Worker` extend `Daemon` with composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: @Bakuriu thanks, the user shouldn't subclass Daemon

Comment: @TokenMacGuy can you expand on the composition implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You can always enforce the non-redeclared type of the method, although it's hackish : [python: enforce that a class method is only called from within another class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803651/python-enforce-that-a-class-method-is-only-called-from-within-another-class-met)

Answer (score 0):

Basically either force other coders to use pylint which will moan about the use of private members or just beat them about the head until they start to listen.  **BTW** *if you are using a decent VCS such as hg, git, svn, then you can find examples of pre-commit hooks that will run pylint against all commits and reject any that fail which may be a way of enforcing the convention and a large number of others - it will also improve the project quality by a large amount so will be well worth the effort - just don't expect to be popular.*

Since you have marked the methods of private you could also vary the signatures from time to time and tell those that moan that they should be leaving them alone - pylint will probably be easier to justify though.