# const reference public member to private class member - why does it work?

Tags: c++

Recently, I found an interesting discussion on how to allow read-only access to private members without obfuscating the design with multiple getters, and one of the suggestions was to do it this way:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  A() : _ro_val(_val) {}
  void doSomething(int some_val) {
    _val = 10*some_val;
  }
  const int& _ro_val;
private:
  int _val;
};

int main() {
  A a_instance;
  std::cout << a_instance._ro_val << std::endl;
  a_instance.doSomething(13);
  std::cout << a_instance._ro_val << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
0
130
```

[GotW#66](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/066.htm) clearly states that object's lifetime starts

> when its constructor completes successfully and returns normally. That is, control reaches the end of the constructor body or an earlier return statement.

If so, we have no guarantee that the `_val` memeber will have been properly created by the time we execute `_ro_val(_val)`. So how come the above code works? Is it undefined behaviour? Or are primitive types granted some exception to the object's lifetime?

Can anyone point me to some reference which would explain those things?

Comment: If you're worried about this, you should just declare `_val` first in your class definition. Members are initialized in the order in which they're declared. (But as the answers say, you don't need the object to be initialized to form a reference to it.)

Comment: Bear in mind that this will increase the size of the object, and require an extra indirection to access the member, whereas an inline getter will be as efficient as directly accessing the member. It also strikes me as rather more obfuscated than a getter (since you have to look at the constructor definition to figure out what it refers to), but that's just my opinion.

Comment: If you really find that your getters and setters are "obfuscating the design", it might be that there is something wrong in your design. You might be using the God Object anti-pattern. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565095/java-are-getters-and-setters-evil/565158#565158

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the constructor is called an appropriate amount of memory is reserved for the object on Freestore(if you use `new`) or on stack if you create object on local storage. This implies that the memory for `_val` is already allocated by the time you refer it in Member initializer list, Only that this memory is not properly initialized as of yet.

```
_ro_val(_val)
```

Makes the reference member `_ro_val` refer to the memory allocated for `_val`, which might actually contain anything at this point of time.

There is still an Undefined Behavior in your program because, You should explicitly initialize `_val` to `0`(or some value,you choose)in the constructor body/Member Initializer List.The output `0` in this case is just because you are lucky it might give you some other values since `_val` is left unInitialized. See the behavior **[here](http://www.ideone.com/wBDKR)** on gcc 4.3.4 which demonstrates the UB.

But as for the Question, Yes indeed the behavior is **Well-Defined**.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, the whole memory layout for where the object will be stored is determined before we even reach the constructor and this makes the `_ro_val_` reference valid, right?

Comment: @dare: That's the gist of it, yes.

Comment: OK, general question then: Is it permitted to form a reference to an "uninitialized object", where strictly speaking the object actually doesn't exist? Like `void * addr = ::operator new(sizeof(T)); T & r = *(T*)(addr);`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I believe nothing stops creating an reference to an `uninitialized object`,though referencing it should be an UB IMO.

Comment: @Als: Re: UB in _val; Yeah, you're right. The code was just a proof of concept so I didn't care, but thank you - pointing it out will be useful to whoever reads it.

Answer (score 1):

The object's address does not change.

I.e. it's well-defined.

However, the technique shown is just premature optimization. You don't save programmers' time. And with modern compiler you don't save execution time or machine code size. But you do make the objects un-assignable.

Comment: "_premature optimization_" I would rather say premature pessimisation.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is legal (well-defined) to initialize a reference with an uninitialized object. That is legal but standard (well, the latest C++11 draft, paragraph 8.5.3.3) *recommends* using a valid (fully constructed) object as an initializer:

`A reference shall be initialized to refer to a valid object or function.`

The next sentence from the same paragraph throws a bit more light at the reference creation:

`[Note: in particular, a null reference cannot exist in a well-defined program, because the only way to create such a reference would be to bind it to the “object” obtained by dereferencing a null pointer, which causes undefined behavior.]`

I understand that reference creation means binding reference to an object obtained by dereferencing its pointer and that probably explains that the minimal prerequisite for initialization of reference of type T& is having an address of the portion of the memory reserved for the object of type T (reserved, but not yet initialized).

Accessing uninitialized object through its reference can be dangerous.

I wrote a simple test application that demonstrates reference initialization with uninitialized object and consequences of accessing that object through it:

```
class C
{   
public: 
    int _n;

    C() : _n(123)
    { 
        std::cout << "C::C(): _n = " << _n << " ...and blowing up now!" << std::endl;       
        throw 1;
    }
};

class B
{
public: 

    // pC1- address of the reference is the address of the object it refers
    // pC2- address of the object
    B(const C* pC1, const C* pC2)
    {
        std::cout << "B::B(): &_ro_c = " << pC1 << "\n\t&_c = " << pC2 << "\n\t&_ro_c->_n = " << pC1->_n << "\n\t&_c->_n = " << pC2->_n << std::endl; 
    }
};

class A
{
    const C& _ro_c;    
    B _b;
    C _c;

public:     

    // Initializer list: members are initialized in the order how they are 
    // declared in class
    //
    // Initializes reference to _c
    //
    // Fully constructs object _b; its c-tor accesses uninitialized object 
    // _c through its reference and its pointer (valid but dangerous!)
    //
    // construction of _c fails!
    A() : _ro_c(_c), _b(&_ro_c, &_c), _c()
    {
        // never executed 
        std::cout << "A::A()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        A a;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create object of type A" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
B::B(): &_ro_c = 001EFD70
        &_c = 001EFD70
        &_ro_c->_n = -858993460
        &_c->_n = -858993460
C::C(): _n = 123 ...and blowing up now!
Failed to create object of type A
```