# Which exception to throw when there are too many elements in a collection

Tags: c#, exception, collections

I want the collection in my class to be limited to up to 6 elements:

```
public class Foo
{
  private ICollection bars;

  public ICollection Bars
  {
    get { return this.bars; }
    set 
    {
      if (value != null && value.Count > 6)
      {
        throw new Exception("A Foo can only have up to 6 Bars."); // Which exception to throw?
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the proper exception to throw in this case?

According to the documentation, [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) shall be thrown:

> when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid.

But this is not a method.

[`ArgumentOutOfRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception.aspx) shall be thrown:

> when the value of an argument is outside the allowable range of values as defined by the invoked method.

Which is intended fo accessing elements outside the size of the collection, not when the collection is too large.

Is there any other exception that suits better this case?

Comment: Use InvalidOperationException. I'd go with custom exceptions in general

Comment: MSDN talks about a *method* for almost all exceptions. I wouldn't let that be your barrier. I would base your choice on the overall description, rather than the wording. I'd agree with Ramunas on the InvalidOperationException too - *The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state*

Comment: I think most people suggest wrapping the setter in a separate method since there's extra logic. I  think getters and setters were meant to be extremely simple since they don't have any inherent semantic meaning. I guess I would say I agree with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/565227/1708197

Comment: BTW, you meant `throw new Exception`, right?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Oops. I missed that 'new' word. Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `ArgumentException`.

Why?

It's the argument that has a problem, not the object of type Foo. It the problem would be caused by the object of type Foo, then an `InvalidOperationException` would be more appropriate.

I would not use `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, as there is no range of allowed ICollections. I would use this exception only if the parameter (and not its Count property) is IComparable, and its value is below a minimum or above a maximum. Note that there is no hard law that states this as the rule to follow, it's just what feels intuitive to most .NET developers.

At least as important as the type of the exception, is the message though. Make sure that clearly explains what the real problem is. The message should be targeted at the developer of the calling code, not at an end user, because the developper can and should write code that never throws this exception. It's what Eric Lippert would call a [boneheaded exception](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) and Krzysztof Cwalina would call a [usage error](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2007/01/30/exceptionhierarchies.aspx).

Finally, don't focus on the word "method". A property has a get method and a set method. The code that is throwing the exception is in the set method, as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 5):

I would go with the `ArgumentException` (or `InvalidOperationException` as per @Ramunas suggestion).

**Explanation:**
Regarding the `But this is not a method.` statement, at the bottom line, there is no real difference between a  method and a property.
Meaning:

```
 public ICollection Bars
  {
    get { return this.bars; }
    set 
    {
      if (value != null && value.Count > 6)
      {
        throw Exception("A Foo can only have up to 6 Bars."); // Which exception to throw?
      }
    }
  }
```

Is equivalent to:

```
Public ICollection get_Bars()
{    
    return this.bars;    
}

Public ICollection set_Bars(ICollection value)
{    
  if (value != null && value.Count > 6)
  {
    throw new Exception("A Foo can only have up to 6 Bars."); // Which exception to throw?
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are setting constraints on what "too large" means, you can set a `ConstraintException`. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.constraintexception(v=vs.90).aspx), `ConstraintException` "Represents the exception that is thrown when attempting an action that violates a constraint.". Hope this helps.