# Storing properties on relational database without using getters

Tags: java, oop, relational-database

I recently read about not using getters and setters in Java (e.g. [When are getters and setters justified](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21802/when-are-getters-and-setters-justified)).

I do not know if this is actually the best way to do object oriented programming. Anyway, supposing that I do not use getters in my code, how can I store data on a relational db? When I started using Java two years ago I used to do something like the following:

```
public void createTitle(Title title) {

    // ... some code here ...

    String sql = "INSERT INTO titles (title_id, name) "
            + "VALUES (TITLES_SEQ.NEXTVAL,?)";
    preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, title.getName()); // Here is the getter
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    // ... other code here ...
}
```

How can I save the `title` with its properties (`name`, in this case) in my relational database if I do not have the `title.getName()` getter? This is just an example, but I hope it makes sense.

Some related discussions:

- [When are getters and setters justified](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/21802/when-are-getters-and-setters-justified)
- [Are getters and setters poor design? Contradictory advice seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565095/are-getters-and-setters-poor-design-contradictory-advice-seen)
- [Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Answer (score 0):

I don't why...  But how you have to make the property name of title public and access it via the dot notation e.G title.name

Comment: From what I am reading about OO and encapsulation, using public fields is quite discouraged. Actually, it is often referred as being an "evil" practice.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using getters/setters one would only have to make the variables public (or protected, as the case may be) for the dot-accessors to work in their place.

`title.name` instead of `title.getName()`

There's two sides of the coin:

One says that public fields are bad and *expose too much*, and the other says simple objects should *stay simple* and not require getters/setters to accomplish the same things.

If you have a strong need to disallow setting a variable (read-only), then privatizing it and making a getter is the way to go.
There's a similar process for write-only variables but with only setters and no getters.

From my personal experience, if I can expose a variable without exposing dangerous side-effects to the end user, then I go ahead and make the field public. Otherwise I close up the field's access as much as possible.