# Is using a reference as a return value considered as bad coding style?

Tags: c++, return-type

I got a question regarding to these two possibilities of setting a value:

Let's say I got a string of a class which I want to change. I am using this:

```
void setfunc(std::string& st) { this->str = st; }
```

And another function which is able to do the exact same, but with a string reference instead of a void for setting a value:

```
std::string& reffunc() { return this->str; }
```

now if I am going to set a value I can use:

```
std::string text("mytext");
setfunc(text);
//or
reffunc() = text;
```

Now my question is if it is considered bad at using the second form of setting the value. 
There is no performance difference.

Comment: You don't need `this->` in class member functions.

Comment: `this` makes things more explicit, a good practice to eliminate ambiguity.

Comment: In the second case you could just as well make the `str` public.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès: Yes and no. You have to balance this advantage with the avoidance of verbosity.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I disagree. To disambiguate from parameter names I usually just use a postfixed `_` on the member or parameter symbol (much shorter).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès - Using `this` strikes me as the programmer is unsure of what he is doing

Comment: In a perfect world, neither setters nor functions that return a mutable object would exist. (Direct access to a data member? That's pure evil from the perspective of this perfect world point of view.) Creating such a perfect world programming environment is the goal of pure functional languages such as Haskell. But even Haskell cannot achieve this ideal, so it provides a back door, monads. In the real world, we occasionally do need to change values. How that is best accomplished is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @DavidHammen Changing values is of course needed, but the way we do it is important and affects readability. The second way the object is changed in the example in the question does not offer anything more than the first one. It is an issue of trade-off, but as mentioned in the question, there is no preference other than clean coding.

Comment: @BoPersson I was taught that i should use a setter or getter instead of making a variable public, I don't really see a reason in these sort of variables where you only change a value and so I just made a setter

Comment: @anon - There are definitely different opinions here, see [Are getters and setters poor design?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565095/are-getters-and-setters-poor-design-contradictory-advice-seen) Without knowing what your class does, and what `str` means, we cannot tell.

Answer (score 3):

The reason to have getters and setters in the first place is that the class can protect its invariants and is easier to modify.

If you have only setters and getters that return by value, your class has the following freedoms, without breaking API:

- Change the internal representation. Maybe the string is stored in a different format that is more appropriate for internal operations. Maybe it isn't stored in the class itself.
- Validate the incoming value. Does the string have a maximum or minimum length? A setter can enforce this.
- Preserve invariants. Is there a second member of the class that needs to change if the string changes? The setter can perform the change. Maybe the string is a URL and the class caches some kind of information about it. The setter can clear the cache.

If you change the getter to return a const reference, as is sometimes done to save a copy, you lose some freedom of representation. You now need an actual object of the return type that you can reference which lives long enough. You need to add lifetime guarantees to the return value, e.g. promising that the reference is not invalidated until a non-const member is used. You can still return a reference to an object that is not a direct member of the class, but maybe a member of a member (for example, returning a reference to the first name part of an internal name struct), or a dereferenced pointer.

But if you return by non-const reference, almost all bets are off. Since the client can change the value referenced, you can no longer rely on a setter being called and code controlled by the class being executed when the value changes. You cannot constrain the value, and you cannot preserve invariants. Returning by non-const reference makes the class little different from a simple struct with public members.

Which leads us to that last option, simply making the data member public. Compared to a getter returning a non-const reference, the only thing you lose is that the object returned can no longer be an indirect member; it has to be a direct, real member.

On the other side of that equation is performance and code overhead. Every getter and setter is additional code to write, with additional opportunities for errors (ever copy-pasted a getter/setter pair for one member to create the same for another and then forgot to change one of the variables in there?). The compiler will probably inline the accessors, but if it doesn't, there's call overhead. If you return something like a string by value, it has to be copied, which is expensive.

It's a trade-off, but most of the time, it's better to write the accessors because it gives you better encapsulation and flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot see the definition of the member `str`.
If it's private, your `reffunc()` exposes a reference to a private member; you're writing a function to violate your design, so you should reconsider what you're doing.
Moreover, it's a reference, so you have to be sure that the object containing `str` still exists when you use that reference.
Moreover, you are showing outside implementation details, that could change in the future, changing the interface itself (if `str` becomes something different, `setfunc()`'s implementation could be adapted, `reffunc()`'s signature has to change).

It's not wrong what you wrote, but it could be used in the wrong way. You're reducing the encapsulation. It's a design choice.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine. However, you have to watch out for these pitfalls:

- **the referenced object is modifiable.** When you return a non-`const` reference, you expose data without protection against modifications. Obvious, but be aware of this anyway!
- **referenced objects can go out of sope.** If the referenced object's lifetime ends, accessing the reference will be undefined behavior. However, they can be used to extend the lifetime of temporaries.

Comment: exactly, you have to watch out if you define the object **in** the function. The returned reference may be invalid. It works for std::string because its **copy-constructor** is well-defined and can pass the contents found in the function's std::string-object to the return value.

Answer (score 1):

The way you used the `reffunc()` function is considered bad coding. But (as mentioned in the comments), generally speaking, returning references is not bad coding.

Here's why `reffunc() = text;` is considered bad coding:

People usually do not expect function calls on the left hand of an assignment, but on the right side. The natural expectation when seeing a function call is that it computes and returns a value (or rvalue, which is expected to be on the right hand side of assignment) and not a reference (or lvalue, which is expected to be on the left hand side of assignment).

So by putting a function call on the left hand side of the assignment, you are making your code more complicated, and therefore, less readable. Keeping in mind that you do not have any other motivations for it (as you say, performance is the same, and it usually is in these situations), good coding recommends that you use a "set" function.

Read the great book ["Clean Code"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) for more issues on clean coding.

As for returning references in functions, which is the title of your question, it is not always bad coding and is sometimes required for having cleaner and briefer code. Specifically many operator overloading features in c++ work properly if you return a reference (see operator[] in std::vector and the assignment operator which usually help the code become more readable and less complex. See the comments).

Comment: You're answering the question in the description, but not the question in the title, with the latter being broader. I'd recommend to update the answer to reflect that, or prompt the asker to change the title to: "is using function returned reference to set values bad practice?".

Comment: You didn't specify which of `setfunc` versus `reffunc` is considered "bad coding." Based on the answer, I'm assuming you meant `reffunc`. Which is worse is a matter of opinion, and that's a problem with this type of question. For a counter point of view, look to `std::vector`. It provides `reference operator[] (size_type pos)`, `const reference operator[] (size_type pos) const`, `reference at (size_type pos)`, `const reference at (size_type pos) const`, but it does not provide `void set(size_type pos, const value_type& val)`.