# Setting And Getting Large No. of Data members

Tags: c++

If I have many private Data members in class... is there any other way of setting and getting instead of declaring setter and getter individually? If so please help.
Thankyou

Comment: You can always make them public

Comment: What are you asking here? Are you looking for a way to get automatically-generated getter/setter functions?

Comment: Please see [Are getters and setters poor design?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565095/are-getters-and-setters-poor-design-contradictory-advice-seen)

Answer (score 0):

**No**.

If it had, then what's the point of private?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really common pattern: It is considered best practice is to have set and get functions instead of making a variable public, even if all the accessors do is modify or return the value.  C++ does not have anything built into the language to reduce the amount of typing needed.

Depending upon your needs, one option is to use a third party library. For example, [Qt provides Q_PROPERTY](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_PROPERTY) which provides what you ask for plus quite a bit more, like serialization.  That type of class is not appropriate for a small, efficient C++ class, but it is a good option for large classes with lots of members (such as a class with all a member for each entry in a dialog box).

Comment: Qt's `Q_PROPERTY` mechanism doesn't really have anything to do with C++. It uses a separate meta-object compiler. So suggesting it as merely a "third party library" is a little bit misleading, I think. As an extra-linguistic mechanism, it is far more than that.

Comment: Yes. To clarify, my point was exactly that: depending on the situation, extra-linguistic features might be a possibility. However, if one of my coders said "I don't need Qt, but I added it to this project just so I don't have to write accessors" then they'd probably get fired..... ;)