# Getters and setters for all the private variables of a class?

Tags: class, oop, object, setter, getter

Is it really necessary or a good practice in general to add **getters** and **setters** on **all** the private variables of a class?

I am not asking about the read-only variables. What I am really asking is the general case, where most of the time we just add **getters** and **setters** in case they'll be needed and don't really know whether they will be used or not.

Comment: Of course not.  In most cases, most of a class's variables should be private fields.  Furthermore, in many cases, properties should be read-only and may not need setters at all.  In the case of those variables that *should* be exposed publicly, however, it is sometimes necessary, but nearly always good practice, to use getters and setters instead of fields, for many reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use getters and setters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters)

Comment: @phoog Thans for the response. But I was not really asking about 'public varibales' vs getters and setters. I edited my question in case it was difficult to unerstand.

Comment: any way implicitly they are set automatically, we can just customize them if needed...

Comment: @ARUN Can you please give an example what you mean by 'if needed'?

Comment: There are many blogs that consider getters/setters evil. I would try to avoid then alltogether. And I would never add them if I do not know if they are needed.

Comment: i happens internally, you can check it during debugging, create a object of a class and set a break point to see the values, you can see there , same field repeated twice

Comment: @CoronA its needed 100%, if you need to control the rights , like make it read only, validation etc

Comment: Only if it makes sense. It makes sense when it helps the user of the class to use the class effectively. The public interface is likely the most important feature of a class in OO design. Everything on there should mean something from a user's perspective and if it does not, it should not be there. The mere existence of a private data member is not a reason to create a public property.

Comment: @ARUN: I almost never need setter properties. The internal state is initialized in the constructor and changed in an oo way with full qualified semantically named methods. Read the attached links, e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565095/are-getters-and-setters-poor-design-contradictory-advice-seen?rq=1 to get an impression how setters could be avoided.

Comment: @CoronA its not needed on daily basis, only if you want to make it readonly, validation simplification, there are some useful things you can do    with it

Comment: Seems like a good question for [programmers.se], as it is not about a specific programming problem, but about best practises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different explanations by different people regarding the use of 'getters' and 'setters'. The purest OO people says, they are [evil](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html).

But actually there are situations where we have to go with them at least in non-direct way.

But I believe that, it is not a good practice to add them seamlessly as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

**As private properties are the internal state of the defining class there is no need to write accessors.**

The benefits are:

- faster code execution (less function calls),
- higher readability and maintainability (lower LOC),
- accessibility to private properties only for the defining class.

Comment: I am in difficulty in understanding what you are trying to say.

Comment: I'm writing that you SHOULD NOT use accessors for private property.

Comment: But there are lots of situations where you have to create accessors right?

Comment: Objects should not be a public data holder - it's not a data structure. Accessors create dependencies between objects and object mutability. That's why you should always avoid public accessors. Private and protected accessors has no benefits.

Answer (score -2):

It is not necessary to write getter or setter for all private variables.
It is just a good practice. 
But without any public function you can not access the private data(variable) of the class.

Comment: It is actually the opposite - it is bad practice to expose unnecessary information as you will likely create unwanted dependencies to private data. Information hiding is one of the key principles - which gets obsolete if you can access all the contained data via accessor methods.