# Need help understanding this piece of code from a book

Tags: c++

This code is from "Sams Teach Yourself C++".It might be something simple but I'm having a hard time trying to figure this out. I get the same output if I don't use the getSpeed() method. So do I need this? If not, why does this book use it?

```
#include <iostream>

class Tricycle 
{
public :
    int getSpeed();
    void setSpeed(int speed);
    void pedal();
    void brake();
private :
int speed;
};

int Tricycle::getSpeed()   //<-- Why do I need this method
{
    return speed;
}

void Tricycle::setSpeed(int newSpeed) 
{
    if (newSpeed >= 0)
    {
        speed = newSpeed;
    }
}

void Tricycle::pedal() 
{
    setSpeed(speed + 1);
    std::cout << "\nPedaling; tricycle speed " << speed << " mph\n";
}

void Tricycle::brake() 
{
    setSpeed(speed - 1);
    std::cout << "\nBraking ; tricycle speed " << speed << " mph\n";
}

int main()
{
    Tricycle wichita;

    wichita.setSpeed(0);
    wichita.pedal();
    wichita.pedal();
    wichita.brake();
    wichita.brake();
    wichita.brake();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read up on getters and setters. There is an ongoing debate whether you need them in c++ or YAGNI. Here is a nice list of [C++ books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: It's not used in the code you show. presumably it will come up later. It's an accessor function.

Comment: For sake of completeness and most importantly encapsulation the method `getSpeed()` is defined. So that you can have/access the current speed of `Tricycle` at any point of time.

Comment: It's all a bad abstraction really. On my real bike, I must use `pedal()` to get some speed (and even to maintain it). There is no `setSpeed` unless you have a powered bike. See [Are getters and setters poor design?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565095/are-getters-and-setters-poor-design-contradictory-advice-seen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Method return the Value from Speed.

So if you call setSpeed with value greater as 0 then the Speed Value are set to the new Value. Declared as private int variable.

As example

```
int main()
{
Tricycle wichita;
wichita.setSpeed(10);
int mySpeed= wichita.getSpeed();
}
```

The Value of mySpeed is now 10.

Answer (score 0):

Since Speed is a private variable, you cannot retrive/set its value outside the class scope. So here we have used setSpeed and getSpeed public functions through which we can retrive/set Speed to tricycle object outside the class scope.

For example,

```
Tricycle myTricycle = new Tricycle();
```

// to set speed of tricycle use,

```
myTricycle.setSpeed(100);
```

// to retrive speed of tricycle object use,

```
myTricycle.getSpeed(); // returns 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because  you cannot access the `private` members directly from the `main()` function or somewhere else. But you can use a `public` function to access the `private` elements of an object of any class. In spite of this, you cannot access those private elements. In your code, `speed` is a `private` member and to get the value of this, a `public` function namely `getSpeed` is being used.